# MySQL 8.0 vs Percona

Tags: magento2, database

We're setting up a new Magento 2.4 project. As we can see in the technology stack requirements, the recommendation for database is MySQL 8.0.

Could anyone explain whether it's better to choose MySQL or Percona? I've seen many projects using Percona (my former company preferred this option for all projects). Are there any particular cases where one might be better than the other one?

I'm interested in the Magento Open Source Edition :)

Thanks for sharing your knowledge